# How to implement Java-like async behavior in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I know how to implement an async operation in Java like this

Instantiate a new thread -> thread do time-consuming stuff(disk IO or network activity) -> thread finishes its job and pass result to main thread

I'm trying to do the same thing in python but could not find a way...
I have read about `async` and `await`, `multiprocessing.Pool`. Neither gives me an clear idea on how to achieve the same thing.

The nearest way I found is `multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async(Callable,Iterable,Callback)`.But this thing cannot be instantiate in a class since it needs to be wrapped in `if __name__=="__main__"` and the `__name__` is my class name.

Any elegant way to do async in Python?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Thread Basics

Take a look at the `threading` module.

An example :

```
from threading import Thread

# instanciate a new thread
t = Thread(target=my_task)
# let it do the time-consuming stuff
t.start()
# do extra stuff while t is working
do_extra_stuff()
# wait for t to finish
t.join()
```

## Getting Task Result

However, if you want to get a value from `my_task`, you'll need to either use global variable, mutable parameter or wrap your task into a class extanding `Thread`.

Here's an example with a wrapping class :

```
class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.result = None

    def run(self):  # this is the Thread method you need to override
        # the time consuming stuff
        self.result = some_result

# same as before, but using the new class, so no need to specify target.
t = MyThread()
t.start() # will call t.run() for you. Never call t.run yourself (you'll lose every benefit from using Thread)
t.join() # wait for t to be finished before getting result
print(t.result)
```

## Passing Arguments

To pass arguments to the task (including the callback), you can either put them as class fields and fill them in the construcor, or use the `args` kwarg from `Thread`'s construcor, like this :

```
t = Thread(target=task_with_parametters, args=(arg1, arg2))
```

`Thread` will call `task_with_parametters` like this :

```
task_with_parametters(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: Can I implement a call back using using this method?

Comment: Edited with a new example, is this what you need ?

Comment: Thanks for helping! Partially yes, but the join still blocks the main thread, I need a call back mechanism which calls a function(this function is somehow defined when we construct the thread) when the thread finishes its job.

Comment: Edited with 2 possibilities on how to pass arguments (and therefore the callback) to the task.